# Div does not getting scroll if it's previous div is visible and height is more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here you can see that div while has D1, D2... data is large than the size of the div, so ideally it should have the scroll bar, but if I click on the Filter link than D1,D2... data div should increase the size, Here my data is dynamic so I can not specify any height to DIV,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#filter-text").click(function(){
   var  a =  $("#filter-option").toggle();
 if(a.css("display")=="block"){
  $("#data").css("height","80%");
 }else{
  $("#data").css("height","96%");
 }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:#efefef;position:absolute;">
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;">
 <div id="filter" style="border:1px solid #00FF00;float:left;overflow:auto;width:100%;">
  <div id="filter-text" style="cursor:pointer; color:#0000ff;height:4%;" >Filter</div>
  <div id="filter-option" style="height:80px;">
   This should be hide on clicking of filter
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="data" style="border:1px solid #0000FF;overflow:auto;float:left;width:100%;max-height:80%;position:relative;">
  <table>
   <tr><td>This div must have scroll bar if its height is higher than parent</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D6</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D7</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D9</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D10</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D11</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D12</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D13</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D14</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D15</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D16</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D17</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D18</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D19</td></tr>
   <tr><td>D20</td></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove height:500px; from div, so that the background will cover full div, or else replace height with min-height.

Comment: I can not remove that height, My container provide me only 500px of height, so I have to design view only in between this height

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awuutyjo/).

Maybe it can help you.

```
 <div id="data" style="border:1px solid #0000FF;overflow:auto;position:absolute;bottom:0;top:100px;">
```

If you fix #data div by top and bottom, scroll will show.

Comment: Hi, In your code  when I Click on Filter button then Filter DIV get Collapse but the Data part div wont come up and it shows the same rows as it was before the Collapsing the filter DIV

Comment: This is due to the fact that #data div had absolute position. top: 100px means that the upper border of #data div will be located at a distance of 100 pixels from the upper border of the parent element. Other conditions are ignored. You can change positioning of the div. This fiddle just to illustrate the reasons why scrolling did not show up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter-text").click(function(){
        $("#filter-option").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:#efefef;">
            <div id="parent" style="position:relative; height:100%;">
                
                <div id="filter" style="border:1px solid #00FF00;position:relative;overflow:auto; /*height:20%;*/">
                    <div id="filter-text" style="cursor:pointer; color:#0000ff;" >Filter</div>
                    <div id="filter-option" style="height:80px;">
                        This should be hide on clicking of filter
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="data" style="border:1px solid #0000FF;overflow:auto; height:80%;">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>This div must have scroll bar if its height is higher than parent</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D1</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D3</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D4</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D5</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D6</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D7</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D8</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D9</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D10</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D11</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D12</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D13</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D14</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D15</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D16</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D17</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D18</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D19</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>D20</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div sytle="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, when you run your code and click on Filter option then It wont collapse the Grin DIV, So the below part with data will have the same height too

Comment: Then just remove the height on filter div element, <div id="filter" style="border:1px solid #00FF00;position:relative;overflow:auto; /*height:20%;*/">

Comment: Hi, If I remove the height of the filter 20% then the data div height want increase without help of JS

Comment: I want to do something like this, step1(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHhxI12LRUeDZBdHF6bDg3aGc/view?usp=sharing), and after clicking on filter it show like step2(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHhxI12LRUV2tNczBBb215eW8/view?usp=sharing), I want to do this without help of Javascript for increase and decrease of heigh of data DIV

Comment: resize the Div height onclick using css is bit difficult, alteast we need some triggers from javascript. Here is the alternate version. i hope this will solve http://jsfiddle.net/dineshhv/7dbL96y5/

Comment: That is true, But sometime what happens we have only fixed size of screen UI, so If filter is collapsible then we can get more screen part, so in that case I have to provide filter collapse option too. (This is mandatory requirement I can not avoid it)